# How can I use Log4Net to write log to my Blob in Azure Web Sites

Tags: azure, log4net, azure-storage, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

Since Azure Web Sites [cannot use DiagnosticsMonitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457204/diagnosticmonitor-in-azure-web-site), how can we write our Log4Net logging to specific Blob?

Answer (score 3):

There's a [log4net Azure Appender](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Appender.Azure) that supports writing to a Blob.